# Pytesseract unable to be used whatsoever but files are read

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

While writing a program, I wanted to use Pytesseract to get text from images, but upon installation, I found it could not be imported. This error message was raised:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py:255, in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    254 try:
--> 255     proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
    256 except OSError as e:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py:951, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask)
    948             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
    949                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
--> 951     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    952                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
    953                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
    954                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
    955                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
    956                         errread, errwrite,
    957                         restore_signals,
    958                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
    959                         start_new_session)
    960 except:
    961     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

File ~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py:1420, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session)
   1419 try:
-> 1420     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1421                              # no special security
   1422                              None, None,
   1423                              int(not close_fds),
   1424                              creationflags,
   1425                              env,
   1426                              cwd,
   1427                              startupinfo)
   1428 finally:
   1429     # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
   1430     # handles that only the child should have open.  You need
   (...)
   1433     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
   1434     # ReadFile will hang.

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TesseractNotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 12
     10 box = {'top':706, 'left':2992, 'width':27, 'height':12}
     11 pic = np.asarray(sct.grab(box))
---> 12 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(pic)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py:423, in image_to_string(image, lang, config, nice, output_type, timeout)
    418 """
    419 Returns the result of a Tesseract OCR run on the provided image to string
    420 """
    421 args = [image, 'txt', lang, config, nice, timeout]
--> 423 return {
    424     Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
    425     Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
    426     Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    427 }[output_type]()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py:426, in image_to_string.<locals>.<lambda>()
    418 """
    419 Returns the result of a Tesseract OCR run on the provided image to string
    420 """
    421 args = [image, 'txt', lang, config, nice, timeout]
    423 return {
    424     Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
    425     Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
--> 426     Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    427 }[output_type]()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py:288, in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout, return_bytes)
    277 with save(image) as (temp_name, input_filename):
    278     kwargs = {
    279         'input_filename': input_filename,
    280         'output_filename_base': temp_name,
   (...)
    285         'timeout': timeout,
    286     }
--> 288     run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    289     filename = f"{kwargs['output_filename_base']}{extsep}{extension}"
    290     with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py:260, in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    258         raise
    259     else:
--> 260         raise TesseractNotFoundError()
    262 with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string:
    263     if proc.returncode:

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

which would make sense, except throughout the entire error (see line 419), it has been referencing Pytesseract's code. For reference, I was originally using Spyder through Conda when getting the error but got irritated at a lack of progress and am currently using Jupyter.

So far I have: uninstalled and reinstalled Pytesseract roughly 10 times through both Windows command prompt and Conda command prompt, updated Conda, updated Spyder, and tested EVERY one of my packages to make sure it's an error with the package and not with my IDE, which all work (other than this one obviously!) I've also read through documentation in case it was an issue with the way I wrote the code, but to me it looks right.

Thank you for any help!